# Why are state-space filters good for time-varying systems?

Tags: filters, audio, filter-design

"The [state-space filter representation](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/State_Space_Filters.html) is especially powerful for time-varying linear systems."

Why is this the case?
What is the explanation behind the claim?

Comment: ... it's actually in the next half-sentence:

Comment: *… and also for time-varying linear systems (in which case any or all of the matrices in Eq. (G.1) may have time subscripts n*

Comment: it allows you to represent a time-variant system with only one dimension that you need to change over time. If you tried to formulate the system in time domain, you'd be two- or three dimensional.